# Line breaking for authors of a theorem

Tags: line-breaking, theorems

I want to cite a theorem of 7 authors. The theorem enivornment I use does not break lines, so the last name is way off the margin. Anyone knows how to deal with this?

Here is the beginning of the document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{theorem} 
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem} 

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}[ Author1, Author2, Author3, Author4, Author5, Author6, Author7 \cite{manyauthored}] 
... 
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

so Theorem number and the authors' names are just too long and it does not break the line.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to answer without any details. Can you maybe add a minimal working example to illustrate your problem, so that it is easier to help you out? (Remember to add all the relevant details such as documentclass and required packages)

Comment: Here is the beginning of the document:

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.eps,.png,.jpg,.mps}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{etex}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

In the document I have 
\begin{thm}[ Author1, Author2, Author3, Author4, Author5, Author6, Author7 \cite{manyauthored}]
...
\end{thm}

so Theorem number and the authors' names are just too long and it does not break the line.

Comment: You can actually edit your original question so that it contains this information.

Comment: The `amsthm` package doesn't pack the optional argument in a box, so it will break.  (You don't want the space at the beginning though.)

Comment: Remove the calls to `epsfig` and `epstopdf` (the former is obsolete and the latter is automatically loaded if needed); there is no need to specify `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions`. And, as @barbarabeeton says, do `\usepackage{amsthm}` in place of `\usepackage{theorem}` (which, by the way, is obsolete as well). Also `\usepackage{etex}` should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Let me examine the code you show in the preamble

`\documentclass[11pt]{article}`

`\usepackage{amssymb}`
`\usepackage{amsmath}`
`\usepackage{graphicx}`
<s>`\usepackage{epsfig}`</s> ①
<s>`\usepackage{epstopdf}`</s> ②
<s>`\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.eps,.png,.jpg,.mps}`</s> ③
`\usepackage{multicol}`
<s>`\usepackage{theorem}`</s> ④
<s>`\usepackage{etex}`</s> ⑤

`\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}`

`\begin{document}`

`\begin{thm}[ Author1, Author2, Author3, Author4, Author5, Author6, Author7 \cite{manyauthored}]`
`...`
`\end{thm}`

`\end{document}`

The strike-outs denote lines you should remove; here are the reasons:

① Obsolete package
② Automatically loaded if need arises
③ Redundant, but it might be useful
④ Obsolete package
⑤ Obsolete package

Solution for your problem: load `amsthm`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[Author1, Author2, Author3, Author4, Author5, Author6, Author7 \cite{manyauthored}]
...
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very nice the new formattation with the circle numbers.

Comment: thank you very much!